# At what temperature does simple syrup freeze?

Tags: freezing, temperature, syrup

I would like to freeze mint flavored simple syrup into ice cubes, and store them for a while. I tried this with a 2 to 1 simple syrup and it did not freeze at all.  Would this work for 1 to 1 simple syrup?

Answer (score 3):

It is pure water and pure sugar (glucose+fuctose) then it will freeze at or about 22F or -5.5C.  At 2:1 it will freeze at 12.5F or -11C.  Use a deep freeze as a normal freezer cannot get it that cold.   This is why slush is made from sugar water as at the freezing point of water the water will freeze while the sugar will not.

Comment: This seems like a pretty good answer but I would appreciate some sources for your numbers. This is partly to satisfy my curiosity.

Comment: A normal freezer [should get cold enough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refrigerator#Temperature_zones_and_ratings). An ice-making compartment probably won't.

Comment: At 8F with 1:1 syrup my freezer makes the cubes firm, but not solid. With 2:1 syrup the cubes are not solid at all. Even with 1:2 syrup, the cubes are only firm and can still be dented with my finger, so popping them out of the tray is more than a little messy.